# Query doesn't consider date range passed in parameters

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, symfony4

I am testing my query with MongoDB, it works perfectly but when I want to return data within a date range I am choosing it return the same data when I tested it without a date range, so it means that doesn't consider the parameters of date time I have passed.

I am working at Symfony4 , MongoDB project , so u can find here the code of my query in the ReactionRepository :

```
public function getCommonFans($pages, $users, $from, $to)
{

   $builder = $this->dm->createAggregationBuilder(FbReaction::class);
   $builder
   ->match()
   ->field('fbPage')->in($pages);
   ->field('fbUser')->in( $users)
   ->field('created_time')->gte($from)
   ->field('created_time')->lte($to);

     $result = $builder->execute()->toArray();

     }
```

An this is the controller :

```
 public function getCommunFansByCompetitor (Request $request){

      $reactionRepository = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()
      ->getRepository(FbReaction::class);


      $from=$to=null;
      try {
        if($request->query->get('from'))
          $from = new \DateTime($request->query->get('from'));

        if($request->query->get('from'))
          $to = new \DateTime($request->query->get('to'));
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
      }


      $listOfCompetitorsPages = $reactionRepository->getCompetitors();


      $listOfUsersOfCurrentPage = $reactionRepository->getFansOfCurrentPage();


      $result = $reactionRepository->getCommonFans( $listOfCompetitorsPages , $listOfUsersOfCurrentPage , $from, $to);


      $response= $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($result, 'json');

      return new Response($response);

  }
```

[this is the document i am working in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B1CM.png)

Comment: Show the documents you expect to match and the values being passed in. Quite a lot of the time the dates turn out to the strings which are not suitable for a `$gte` and `$lte` range.

Comment: hey Neil , I have added a link in my post with the picture of document i am working in it . And when i checked the value of $from i got this : 

object(DateTime)#5718 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2017-01-01 12:10:18.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}

Comment: Please don't include external links or pictures. Show the data in JSON form as it appears when viewed from the `mongo` shell. Compass is not a great tool for showing data in a re-usable state. Also include in your question the "inputs" you are sending to your controller. At a glance though, it looks like your data is in fact stored as BSON Date, however you're probably querying with "strings" and not dates. You need to get [`MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php) and do the conversion.